# Use PHP semaphore in the same script

Tags: php

In my initial PHP script, I use PHP semaphore and i lock the script if it is already launched.

Exemple :

```
$SEMKey = "123521";
$SHMKey = "345843";
$updatedCache = NULL;
$testExecutionScript = NULL;
$seg = sem_get( $SEMKey, 1, 0666, -1);

if($seg === false)
{
    echo "<br />Fail to get semaphore";
}

if(!sem_acquire($seg))
{
    echo "<br />Fail to aquire semaphore".$sem_id;
    sem_remove($seg);
}

$id = shm_attach($SHMKey);
if($id === false)
{
    echo "<br />Fail to attach shared memory.\n";
    sem_remove($seg);
}else
{
    $bool = true;
}

$executionScriptOn = "on";
$executionScriptOff = "off";

if($bool)
{   
    if(shm_has_var($id,1)){

        $testExecutionScript = shm_get_var ($id,1); 

    }else{

        shm_put_var($id, 1, $executionScriptOff);
        $testExecutionScript = $executionScriptOff;
    }

    if(empty($testExecutionScript) || $testExecutionScript === $executionScriptOff)
    { 
        shm_put_var($id, 1, $executionScriptOn);
        $updatedCache = TRUE;

    }else
    {
        $updatedCache = FALSE;
    }
}
sem_release($seg);

if($updatedCache)
{
    echo '<br /> condition : '.shm_get_var($id, 1);
    echo '<br />execute';
    sleep(10);
    shm_put_var($id, 1, $executionScriptOff);
}
```

This code works.

If I use a secondary script with: "shm_get_var" function in an another file, the script signal me when the semaphore variable is On or Off. ( This script serves only to return the semaphore variables content like On or Off ).

But if I relaunching the initial script in my first file ( on an another browser for exemple ) and if the first script is already running ( for simulate that, I use PHP sleep function ), the second instance of the initial script is executed then it should not run.

It isn't possible to launch the same script in two different browsers and respect the content of the semaphore variables ?

Comment: are you trying to realize singleton pattern without class? or you want to have SAME values for all users?

Comment: Nop, I can try. But I prefer a solution without singleton. ( If possible of course ).

Comment: but what do you want to achieve? it is not clear. because if you try `on an another browser for exemple` that php is new environment for each user visiting your website. so to return some UNIQUE for all value - you should keep it not in var but in database or in file, or somehow in memcached server

Comment: Hmmm ok, thx for the link but i dont see what i can change in my code for resolve the problem.